# Display 5 products in a row in angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I wrote following code to display some products on a page but my motive is to display only 5 items in a row.

My code for displaying all products:

```
 <div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" data-ng-repeat="prod in products">
          <div class="ibox">
            <div class="ibox-content product-box">
              <div class="product-imitation">
                <img class="product-image" src="{{prod.productImage}}" />
              </div>
              <div class="product-desc">
                <small class="text-muted">{{prod.productDesc}}</small> <a
                  href="#/" class="product-name"> {{prod.productName}}</a>
                <div class="m-t text-righ">
                  <a href="#/"
                    class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-primary animation_select"
                    data-animation="flipInY">Buy Now<i
                    class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am not able to figure out how to display only 5 products in a row.

Answer (score 2):

you can use limitTo: 5 on ng-repeat.

ng-repeat = "item in items | limitTo: 5"

[working plunker][1]

[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/zWc4hDIMUZ38rGt8TMel?p=preview `<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Hello {{name}}
    <div ng-repeat = "item in items | limitTo: 5">{{item}}</div>
  </body>`

Comment: it displays only 5 elements rest elements are ignored

Answer (score 0):

use AngularJS `limitTo` option with `ng-repeat`.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

 Total objects in an array: {{ArrVals.length}}

    <p>Displayed 2 objects only</p>
    <div ng-repeat="ArrVal in ArrVals | limitTo:2">
      {{ArrVal}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.ArrVals = [
    {val:1, name: 'A'},
    {val:2, name: 'A'},
    {val:3, name: 'A'},
    {val:4, name: 'A'},
    {val:5, name: 'A'},
    {val:6, name: 'A'},
  ];
})
```

Working Plnkr Code - http://plnkr.co/edit/nRdGZXhMm9nGlwPO5aKf?p=preview